# Another ng-click() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sure this is something fundamental, but I can not find it.  I am trying to send data back to the controller.  I believe the ng-click event is not firing.  This was my attempt to debug the issue.  I believe I have stripped it down to the bare essentials for a simple alert..

here is the controller and the partial view

```js
angular.module('FieldApp', [])
  .controller('FieldCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.createField = function($scope, $http) {
      alert("Create Field");

    }
  })
```

```html
 
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="FieldApp" ng-controller="FieldCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="createField()">Add Field</button>
</div>

<script src="./js/field.js" charset="utf-8">
```

cheers

Comment: Copy pasted your code to jsfiddle and it seems to work well: https://jsfiddle.net/btsjrjkc/

Comment: Remove $scope and $http from parameterised section and use like $scope.createField = function(){ //your code}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a case of not formatting a variable name correctly.  I had myApp in one file and MyApp in another file.  It has been many years since I used a text editor instead of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies parameters in the function are unnecessary. Just declare the function like this:

```
$scope.createField = function() { ... }
```

And you need to reference to the `$window` dependency to show the alert:

```
$window.alert("Create Field");
```

Don't forget the include `$window` in the dependencies list of your controller (`.controller('FieldCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {`).

But it's better to just do `console.log("Create Field");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The window reference is not necessary. This is how I would write your code. I don't know exactly what's going on in your code, but it is usually good practice to set a variable for the module.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var app = angular.module('FieldApp', []);

    app.controller('FieldCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.createField = function() {
             alert("Create Field");   
        };

    }]);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="FieldApp">
        <div ng-controller="FieldCtrl">
            <button ng-click="createField()">Add field</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code segment worked on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. I've created a jsFiddle from it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gcsgggcw/

I've just stripped the javascript links from your html:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="FieldApp" ng-controller="FieldCtrl">
   <button type="button"  ng-click="createField()">Add Field</button>
</div>
```

The cause must be something else; did you checked if all the javascript files are loaded properly in the browser?